# Issue with Powershell SMO SQL Server restore

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo, database-restore

I am running into an issue with doing a Powershell SQL restore. I have this code

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

$backupFile = 'C:\Temp\User_20191029152532.bak'

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"
$backupDevice = New-Object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem") ($backupFile, "File")
$smoRestore = new-object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore")

$smoRestore.NoRecovery = $false;
$smoRestore.ReplaceDatabase = $true;
$smoRestore.Action = "Database"
$smoRestorePercentCompleteNotification = 10;
$smoRestore.Devices.Add($backupDevice)

$smoRestoreDetails = $smoRestore.ReadBackupHeader($server)

"Database Name from Backup Header : " +$smoRestoreDetails.Rows[0]["DatabaseName"]

$smoRestore.Database =$smoRestoreDetails.Rows[0]["DatabaseName"]

$smoRestoreFile = New-Object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile")
$smoRestoreLog = New-Object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile")

$smoRestoreFile.LogicalFileName = $smoRestoreDetails.Rows[0]["DatabaseName"]
$smoRestoreFile.PhysicalFileName = $server.Information.MasterDBPath + "\" + $smoRestore.Database + "_Data.mdf"
$smoRestoreLog.LogicalFileName = $smoRestoreDetails.Rows[0]["DatabaseName"] + "_Log"
$smoRestoreLog.PhysicalFileName = $server.Information.MasterDBLogPath + "\" + $smoRestore.Database + "_Log.ldf"
$smoRestore.RelocateFiles.Add($smoRestoreFile)
$smoRestore.RelocateFiles.Add($smoRestoreLog)

$smoRestore.SqlRestore($server)
```

Everything works fine if I run this. However, I would like to provide a variable for which backup to restore. So I changed the top part of the code to this:

```
$path = 'C:\Temp'
$db_name = 'User'
$file = Get-ChildItem $path '*.bak' | Select-Object basename | Where-Object {$_.basename -like $db_name + '*' }

$backupFile = $path + '\' + $file
```

When I make this change, I start getting the below error.

> Exception calling "ReadBackupHeader" with "1" argument(s): "An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch."
>
> At line:23 char:1
>   + $smoRestoreDetails = $smoRestore.ReadBackupHeader($server)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException

Not really sure why it will not accept the $file variable that I am passing.  If I look at the variable, it is returning the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid issue on my part.  $file did not include the extension.  Adding the .bak to $file fixed the issue.